# Spring 3 web request interceptor - how do I get BindingResult?

Tags: java, web-applications, spring-mvc, interceptor

I realy appreciate Spring 3 anoation driven mapping of Web Controllers

I have a lot of Controllers with signatures like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "solicitation/create",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String handleSubmitForm(Model model, @ModelAttribute("solicitation") Solicitation  solicitation, BindingResult result)
```

But my issue is, that I want to write an interceptor that would ho through BindingResults after processing - how do I get them from HttpRequest or HttpResponse?

as intercpetor methods are with alike signature

```
public boolean postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So with big help from @Axtavt I came to conlusion, that you can get to Bind reuslt from ModelAndView in postHandle method:

```
void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) {
  String key = BindingResult.MODEL_KEY_PREFIX + "commandName";
  BindingResult br = (BindingResult) modelAndView.getModel().get(key);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

After execution of controller method `BindingResult` is stored as a model attribute named `BindingResult.MODEL_KEY_PREFIX + <name of the model attribute>`, later model attributes are merged into request attributes. So, before merging you can use Hurda's own answer, after merging use:

```
request.getAttribute(BindingResult.MODEL_KEY_PREFIX + "solicitation")
```

Comment: where in the documentation can I find such informations? (I've started with Spring 3.0]

Comment: @Hurda: Accessing `BindingResult` without standard facilities (such as `<form:errors>` tag) is a rather advanced topic, so placement of `BindingResult` in the model described in its javadoc: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/BindingResult.html

Comment: So I just tested that and the BindResult aint in request attributes, but in the model. But that's OK because ModelAndView is part of void     postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView)  signature