# Session Properties framework

Tags: java, spring, session, properties

Here is my specific question:

There is a project which contains a lot of pages which uses *Spring Framework* on *Java*.

There is some kind of Admin users and department users.

The problem is that an admin user should see all kind of users(all information).

Sometimes an admin might delete some users: **This method should be accomplished**.

My project leader told me to look at the session properties access and search if there is a framework for that which should work with *Spring*.

How could I manage that?
Is there a framework for that? If not what is the best way ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Comment: if i am reading it correctly u want role based system? if yes go with spring security

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227395/spring-3-0-set-and-get-session-attribute     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886065/spring-3-web-request-interceptor-how-do-i-get-bindingresult   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077138/integrating-interceptor-to-web-requests-in-spring-3-0

Comment: is spring security  different  framework than spring or ?

Comment: i searched spring security, it restrict system but my problem is that i want to reach all session properties and whenever i dont want i should be able to remove some session property.is there a framework for that ?

Answer (score 2):

You can by using `Acegi` security framework, it integrates with `Spring` framework. To solve your issue, you have to set current user into `Http Session` (`Spring-Acegi` has a specified class for this) and read current user whenever needed.

`Spring + Acegi` has more features like :

- Multiple level security by multiple level filters
- Concurrent session support, which limits the number of simultaneous logins permitted by a principal.
- Support `ACL` (`Access Control List`) and Object Domain Security.
- Support authentication&Authorization.
- and a lot more

It has a lot of useful utilities and structures.

You can see more information at the following links:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Security
- http://www.tfo-eservices.eu/wb_tutorials/media/SpringAcegiTutorial/HTML/SpringAcegiTutorial-1_1-html.html

Comment: can i access all session properties with that ? can i remove a session property whenever i want ?

Comment: Adding/removing session properties has nothing to do with this, they are the properties of the request/response located in the servlet

Comment: I m on proggress on searching my duty.I have found that i can do with requestIntercepter(). but my leader want from me  if there is a framework it would be easy way.

Comment: @user1091692 Yes, you can add/remove properties in session by `Spring+Acegi` frameworks.

Comment: do you know any example add/remove properties in session by spring+acegi frameworks ?

Comment: Acegi security framework became part of Spring framework and now called Spring Security, by the way

Comment: guys do you know any example for that ? i need to apply my project...Still searching

Comment: @vacuum Yes, it is called `Spring Security` but `Acegi` become standalone also.

Comment: @user1091692 You can find very simple and complex sample in web.

Comment: @user1091692 You have to read a `Spring Security` tutorial, if you want fast solve your problem, you have to it manually by `HttpSession` `getAttribute` and `setAttribute` method.

Comment: hey again,i have one more question. we can get current user with getAttribute but what if i want to reach all users on servers? how can i get it?

Comment: your means is get all current users in server?

Answer (score 2):

To add Spring Security to existing Spring app follow next example:
http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hello-world-example/

And I recommend you to read their [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity.html). Spring have really good documentation.

[Another example](http://krams915.blogspot.com/2010/12/spring-security-mvc-integration_18.html)

Comment: your examples for  integrating Spring Security  with Spring MVC web application to secure URL access. But i need to add/remove session properties for example :S

Comment: @user1091692 if you are talking about HttpSession, then you can put properties(or attribute) from SpringMVC in any controller.
But as I undertand, you need to separete regular users and admin users, which is done by role-based system in Spring Security.

Comment: yeah i need to separete users.i just want to remove their session properties whenever admin want .is there a example for that in spring security?

Comment: @user1091692 I dont think, there is concrete example for your problem.
To remove user session properties with admin you can create some sort of admin page, where you will put admin controls. Access for this page will have only admin users. This can make easy with spring Security.